# Getting variable from function

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for me to get the file url from this function without changing the javascript and without running the function?

```
  jwplayer('jsCmgPlayer').setup({
    flashplayer: 'http://website.com/player.swf',
    file: 'http://website.com/0015980.mp3',
    autostart: true,
 'skin': 'http://www.website.com/skin.xml',
 'controlbar': 'bottom',
    height: 28,
    width: 620
  });
```

I want to get `http://website.com/0015980.mp3` as a separate variable.

Comment: Look at the plugin's docs and see if there is a method to get an option value.  Maybe there's a method like `getConfig` or something.

Comment: That statement is running the function already.

Comment: By the way, you're calling setup yourself, so the value you provide as the url is coming from you. So you can do with it what you want. If you give us a little context code we can help you find the cleanest solution.

Comment: In your snippet, the value you want is assigned to a property of an object literal, which is _passed as an argument_. Why not `var obj = {flashplayer:'http://',...};`, basically everything between the curlies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. If you don't run the function you can't access the property over the plugins API because it's never set nor can you access it from an outer scope in your JavaScript code. The argument hash is not visible outside of this function.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the function is not run, the object containing the url can't be accessed. You only could try to get the function's source code as a string, and dig around in it e.g. with a regular expression to match that object literal.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript you provide is running the function already. Since *you* are calling the setup code and *you* provide the arguments you can do this:

```
// create the arguments object
var setupArgs = {
    flashplayer: 'http://website.com/player.swf',
    file: 'http://website.com/0015980.mp3',
    autostart: true,
    'skin': 'http://www.website.com/skin.xml',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    height: 28,
    width: 620
}

// setup the plugin
jwplayer('jsCmgPlayer').setup(setupArgs);
```

Now you can use the arguments however you want, to access that url:

```
// use the arguments object for other things
setupArgs.file;
```

Comment: We do not know if he is actually providing the code. It could be a snippet from somewhere included on the server.